# Sorting Array ignoring special characters and integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have been trying to sort and array with strings composed of letters, integers and characters. Here is what I have done:

```
var vList =["IEC - 62877-1 ", "IEC - 60622 ", "CAN/CSA - F382-M89 (2014) ", "Telcordia - GR-3150-CORE ", "UL - 1973"];

vList.sort(function(a,b) {
return a.split(' - ')[0] - b.split(' - ')[0];
});

print(vList)
```

The idea is to sort the array in alphabetical order by using the first letter only element of the string: "IEC", "CAN", "Telecordia", "UL".

the array should look like this:

```
vList = ["CAN/CSA - F382-M89 (2014)", "IEC - 62877-1 ", "IEC - 60622 ","Telcordia - GR-3150-CORE ", "UL - 1973"];
```

Comment: You can't use subtraction as the comparison function when you're comparing strings. That only works with numbers.

Comment: Get the first word of each argument, then use `if` statements to return `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending on the order.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to only sort by the beginning first string characters, and not the whole string, you can just do a localeCompare in the sort function.

```js
var vList =["IEC - 62877-1 ", "IEC - 60622 ", "CAN/CSA - F382-M89 (2014) ", "Telcordia - GR-3150-CORE ", "UL - 1973"];

vList.sort(function(a, b) {
    var string1 = /[a-zA-Z]+/.exec(a);
    var string2 = /[a-zA-Z]+/.exec(b);
    if(string1 && string2) {
        return string1[0].localeCompare(string2[0]);
    } else {
        return a - b
    }
})

console.log(vList);
```

Just be aware that it will act in ways you might not expect if one of the entries you are trying to sort is "62877-1 IEC", because it will still try to sort based on IEC, even though it is after the numbers. It also only uses "CAN" in the "CAN/CSA" entry because of the forward slash, but it seems like you wanted it that way anyway from the post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in sort function of [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The **`sort()`** method sorts the elements of an array [*in place*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

```js
var vList =["IEC - 62877-1 ", "IEC - 60622 ", "CAN/CSA - F382-M89 (2014) ", "Telcordia - GR-3150-CORE ", "UL - 1973"];

vList.sort();

console.log(vList);
```

A proposal which maintains the original order with [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

```js
var vList =["IEC - 62877-1 ", "IEC - 60622 ", "CAN/CSA - F382-M89 (2014) ", "Telcordia - GR-3150-CORE ", "UL - 1973"],
    mapped = vList.map(function(el, i) {
        return { index: i, letter: el[0] };
    });

mapped.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.letter.localeCompare(b.letter) || a.index - b.index;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function(el){
    return vList[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The OP wants the list to sort just based off of the beginning letters, not the numbers. So IEC - 62877-1 should sort BEFORE IEC 60622, but that won't happen with the default sort.

Comment: @PeterLaBanca, even if you just get the letters, you get an unstable result. what is the benefit of doing some splitting, without using the numerical part?

Comment: I am just going off of what the OP wrote in their post. They wanted the sort to happen a certain way. I do not know why it needs to be sorted that way.

Comment: @PeterLaBanca, maybe the keeping of the order helps in theis case with same letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very special for your case. However, you have to describe your strings either with a regex or, like you, by splitting it or doing some other stuff. Repair your method to:

```
vList.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.split(' - ')[0].localCompare(b.split(' - ')[0]);
});
```

That uses a local (to the browser language) comparison of strings and returns the correct value.

Comment: Nice approach. However, it is assuming the whitespace around the characters. A more robust solution would use the regex /\s*-/s*/ instead to split, so that whitespace doesn't matter.

Comment: That is right. That is the hard part, I think, where we cannot help felipe ballesteros. Since we don't know a pattern, we cannot give a good regex. However, your solution is more proper, right!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var vList =["IEC - 62877-1 ", "IEC - 60622 ", "CAN/CSA - F382-M89 (2014) ", "Telcordia - GR-3150-CORE ", "UL - 1973"];

vList.sort(function(a,b) {
if(a.split('-')[0]> b.split('-')[0]) 
   return 1;
else if(a.split('-')[0]< b.split('-')[0])
   return -1;
return 0;
})

print(vList);
```

This should work fine. You did everything fine instead of subtract you can use > or greater than and return 1, -1 & 0 accordingly.

Comment: There is a build-in solution for comparing strings, 'localCompare'. You should use it instead of own comparisons.